# Render functional component on variable change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can not get my component to re-render when an internal variable changes. The system I working on uses functional components. The case is like this:

```
export const myComponent = (props: compPropsType) => {
    const myClassNames ....

    let objectList= getObjectList(window.location.hash, props.pageTree);

    window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
        console.log('hello');
        objectList = getObjectList(window.location.hash, props.pageTree);
    });
    return (
        <>
        <header className={headerClassNames}>
            <Block className={...}>
            ...
            <myChildComp objList={objectList}>
            ...
    )
};
```

The problem is to render `<myCildComp>` when the hash updates. (`objectList`is an array of strings, used to create navigation toolbar.)

When I click a link on the page, `hello` is written to console, so the listener is working, but it does not re-render the child component.

Comment: `objectList` isn't in the props or the state, so reassigning the value inside the callback won't do anything to make the component re-render.

Comment: Changing a variable inside a component doesn't cause a re-render. You have a couple of options: 1) Change to a class component and store your objectList in `state` updating it with `setState`. 2: If you're using one of the more modern versions of React you'll have access to the `useState` hook. A third option is to pass this data is from the parent as `props`, then when `props` changes, your component will re-render.

Comment: @JamieDixon I will re-write to a class component. Do I need the listener? And call `setState`from it?
The `myChildComp`can still be a functional component? And take `this.state.objectList`as prop? (`<myChildComp objList={this.state.objectList}>`)

Answer (score 3):

a function component in react is equivalent to the render() function in a class component.

so in your case you're adding an eventListener every time the component is re-rendered which creates a memory leak, you should use `useEffect` hook instead to add it once and remove it when the component/hook is destroyed.

your component doesn't re-render because nothing is telling it to.. components in react only re-render when either state or props changes.. so in your case I think you'd need to add objectList to state combined with `useEffect` hook like so

```js
export const myComponent = (props: compPropsType) => {
    const myClassNames ....
     const [objectList, setObjectList] = useState([])

  const onHashChanged = () => {
    console.log('hello')

    let newObjectList = getObjectList(window.location.hash, props.pageTree)
    setObjectList(newObjectList)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('hashchange', onHashChanged)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('hashchange', onHashChanged)
  }, [])
    return (
        <>
        <header className={headerClassNames}>
            <Block className={...}>
            ...
            <myChildComp objList={objectList}>
            ...
    )
};
```

when using an empty array as a second argument in `useEffect` it will only be called once equivalent to `componentDidMount` and I'm returning a callback function to unsubscribe/remove the listener which works similar to `componentWillUnmount`

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment, I rewrote the function to be a class:

```
export class myComponent extends React.PureComponent<PropsTypes> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {objList = getObjectList(window.location.hash, this.props.pageTree)};
    }
    componentDidMount(): void {
        window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => {
            this.setState({
            breadcrumbList: getObjList(window.location.hash, this.props.pageTree),
            });
        });
    }
    render() {
    return (....
        <myChildComp objList={this.state.objList}>
    ...
```

This works, but it is the best way?

Comment: remove the event listener on componentWillUnmount otherwise you'll have a memory leak and the event listener might still fire even after the component is unmounted.